# How to query samples in relativity?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a large data set with about 100 million rows that I want to 'compress' the data set and get a 1% sample of the entire dataset while ensuring relativity.

**How can such query be implemented?**

Comment: Please tag the question with the RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: @GMB sorry, I forgot but just added it.

Comment: I am just totally lost.  You example percentages already add to 100%, so where would additional ids come from?  You say you want a sample, but the data appears to be summarized as well.  You have not explained what you want clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: create the helper table**

You can use aggregation to group records by `visit_id`, and `CROSS JOIN` with a query that computes the total number of records in the table to compute the distribution percent:

```
CREATE TABLE my_helper AS
SELECT
    t.visit_number,
    COUNT(*) visit_count,
    SUM(t.purchase_id) sum_purchase,
    COUNT(*)/total.cnt distribution
FROM 
    mytable t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable) total
GROUP BY t.visit_number
```

**Step 2: sample the main table using the helper table**

Within a subquery, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY visit_number ORDER BY RANDOM())` to assign a random rank to each record within groups of records sharing the same `visit_id`. Then, in the outer query, you can join on the helper table to select the corect amount of records for each `visit_id`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY visit_number ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
INNER JOIN my_helper h ON h.visit_number = x.visit_number
WHERE x.rn <= 1000000 * h.distribution
```

Side notes:

- this only works if there are indeed more than 1 million record in the source table
- the exact number of records in the output might be slightly below or above 1 million (depending on the distribution in the original table)
- it should be possible to combine both queries into a single one, which would avoid the need to use a helper table

Comment: @Tina: yes, just replace `my_helper` in the second query with the `SELECT` that is in the first query (surrounded with parenthesis).

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to write the query without the cross join?

Comment: @Tina: I would not expect that the `CROSS JOIN` by itself will have a significant performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable. A quick way is to take every nth record only.

1) order by a random column (probably ID)

2) apply a nownum() attribute

3) apply a mod(rownum) = 0 on whatever percent makes sense (e.g. 1% would be rownum mod 100)

You may need steps 1/2 in a sub query and step 3 on the outside.

Enjoy and good luck!